# Java - how to put all words from a textfile with a specific length in a List

Tags: java, file, words

So I have a wordlist called wordlist.txt and I want to put all words that have a specific length, let's say 5, and put them in a list.

First I tried to just get all the words into a list, for testing purposes but I got an error "Cannot resolve symbol 'exists'" when I tried Files.exists, it works in the Main function but not in a class for some reason.
[Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOQO7.jpg)

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
private Path myFile = Paths.get("Resources/wordlist.txt");
if (Files.exists(myFile)){
    try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(myFile)){
        while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
            list.add(fileScanner.nextLine());
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("The file doesn't exists!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you import the Files class into your testing class?

Comment: is this code and main method code written in two separate files and is your first line of code compiled properly

Comment: You may need to remove the `private` identifier.

Comment: because the path "Resources/wordlist.txt" is relative path and while running main function it is possible to find it but not when you are running  your class. Different frameworks have different solutions for reading resources and here you are not mentioning what you are using. Using plain java if resources are located relative to your class then you can use classloader getResourceAsStream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, remove the `private` modifier - it is not allowed to be inside a method. That should resolve your syntax error.

Secondly, I suggest you follow the folder structure as a brief example states below:

```
src/main/java
 - Main.java  
src/main/resources
 - wordlist.txt
```

You are ready you can access the file using the ClassLoader. If `Files.exists(myFile)` returns true, the IOException won't be thrown. Try the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("wordlist.txt").getFile());
try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
        list.add(fileScanner.nextLine());
    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("The file doesn't exists!");
}
```

Finally, the label of the question doesn't match with what do you ask. I am not sure whether I understand "put all words" correctly. Anyway, let's suggest the text file contains one word on each line, thus check it's length and decide to add to the list or not.

```
while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
    String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
    if (line.length() == 5) { // specific length, use a constant is better          
        list.add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's exactly what I meant, it really helped my out thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to add a "/" in the path like this: ("/Resources/wordlist.txt"), because of file pathing to your project.

Tutorial can be seen [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html)